# What is the Trade Paperback reading order before reading the Avengers (vol. 1)?

Tags: marvel, avengers, suggested-order, thor-marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I'm having trouble. I'm a trade paperback person and somewhat new to comics (sorry for all the questions I have). I check them out at my local library. I was just wondering:

• If I read trade paperbacks like the masterworks, is there a specific order to read up on each member (ex. Hulk, Thor) before reading Avenger's masterworks?

• Or should I read each character's large history then go back and read the Avenger masterworks?

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no reading order per se, all major marvel characters were "born" in a short timeline between 1961 and 1964, creating Avengers was a logical decision to counterbalance DC's teams (Mostly Justice League of America).
What i mean is, if you start Avengers from the start you won't miss a lot in the storylines, the only thing you could do is start with Thor, since the villain in Avengers 1 is Loki, but again you won't miss a lot by not doing that.
Crossovers came a bit later